# Awk: Drop last record separator in one-liner

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a simple command (part of a bash script) that I'm piping through awk but can't seem to suppress the final record separator without then piping to sed. (Yes, I have many choices and mine is sed.) Is there a simpler way without needing the last pipe?

```
dolls = $(egrep -o 'alpha|echo|november|sierra|victor|whiskey' /etc/passwd \
| uniq | awk '{IRS="\n"; ORS=","; print}'| sed s/,$//);
```

Without the sed, this produces output like `echo,sierra,victor,` and I'm just trying to drop the last comma.

Comment: There is no awk variable named "IRS". There is "RS" and it is a newline by default so no need to set it if that was your intent. Also, uniq wont detect duplicate entries unless lines are adjacent so you'd be better off with `sort -u` instead, and the egrep will pull out text that's part of larger strings - is that really what you want? Tell us end-to-end what you're trying to do with sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Comment: There shouldn't be any space around the `=` symbol

Comment: Thanks for the note about IRS. I'm a bit of an awk noob and really only use it for pipe processing. If it hadn't been ignored and the separator wasn't a \n already, I'd have had to learn from the bug. :)

I'm using `uniq` rather than `sort -u` because the duplicate names are coming from a single line in /etc/passwd: first the username and then the home directory. They're pretty much guaranteed to be consecutive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need awk, try:

```
egrep -o ....uniq|paste -d, -s
```

Here is another example:

```
kent$  echo "a
b
c"|paste -d, -s
a,b,c
```

Also I think your chained command could be simplified. awk could do all things in an one-liner.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't used the paste command in a very long time and forgot about it completely. That's elegant. Thanks.

N.B.: Your first example has a typo. `paste -d, s` needs to be `paste -d, -s`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of egrep, uniq, awk, sed etc, all this can be done in one single awk command:

```
awk -F":" '!($1 in a){l=l $1 ","; a[$1]} END{sub(/,$/, "", l); print l}' /etc/password
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small and quite straightforward one-liner in awk that suppresses the final record separator:

```
echo -e "alpha\necho\nnovember" | awk 'y {print s} {s=$0;y=1} END {ORS=""; print s}' ORS=","
```

Gives:

```
alpha,echo,november
```

So, your example becomes:

```
dolls = $(egrep -o 'alpha|echo|november|sierra|victor|whiskey' /etc/passwd | uniq | awk 'y {print s} {s=$0;y=1} END {ORS=""; print s}' ORS=",");
```

The benefit of using awk over paste or tr is that this also works with a multi-character ORS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it `bash` here is one way of doing it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read the /etc/passwd file in to an array called names
while IFS=':' read -r name _; do 
  names+=("$name"); 
done < /etc/passwd

# Assign the content of the array to a variable
dolls=$( IFS=, ; echo "${names[*]}")

# Display the value of the variable
echo "$dolls"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "a
b
c" |
```

> ```
> mawk 'NF-= _==$NF' FS='\n' OFS=, RS=
> ```

```
a,b,c
```